# Show two jQuery overlays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

i'm trying to use jQuery to open two overlays on page load. But only the second one shows up. I'm relatively new to javascript, so this maybe a very simple question for you guys.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#overlay-left").overlay({ top: 200, closeOnClick: false, load: true });
    $("#overlay-right").overlay({ top: 500, closeOnClick: false, load: true });
});
```

The two Overlays:

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay-left">
<ul>
    [...]
</ul>
```

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay-right">
<ul>
    [...]
</ul>
```

I could really use some guidance here. Any help or suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming the `.overlay()` is part of a jQuery plugin, as this is NOT part of jQuery's core API. Can you please include the plugin you're using? Perhaps [this one](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/)?

Comment: If you are using jquerytools, your code extract is not complete, cause the triggers are missing. Please have a look on the [minimal setup for overlay](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

in the docs of the jquery overlay plugin, the plugin  you obviously use,

there is an option

> oneInstance : true
>
> By default, there can be only one overlay on the
>   page at once. Setting this property to false allows you to have
>   multiple overlay instances.

check this link http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/multiple.html